# как правильно исключить элементы из массива?

Tags: javascript

есть массив вида [image: массив]

как получить отсортированный массив без false элементов?

Comment: `const newArray = array.filter((item) => item !== false)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При помощи метода `filter()`, который принимает callback-функцию, которая может возвращать условие.

```js
const array = [false, false, true, 2, 'string'];

const filteredArray = array.filter(item => item != false);
// вернёт [true, 2, 'string']
```

Answer (score 0):

Если необходимо убрать все Boolean значения из массива, можно воспользоваться функцией [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), которая возвращает название типа.

```js
const array = [false, false, true, 2, 'string', false, {}, []];

const filteredArray = array.filter(item => typeof item !== 'boolean');

console.log(filteredArray);
```